# Simplify Swift data struct

Tags: swift, struct

Any suggestion on how to simplify this data struct? The data will be saved as a dictionary on the user's drive and when I read the data from the drive I have to convert them back to `Member` for easy accessing the properties.

I would like to have it typesafe.

```swift
struct Member {
    var id: Int
    var firstname: String
    var lastname: String
    var address: String?
    var zipCode: Int?
    var city: String?

    enum Value: String {
        case id = "id"
        case firstname = "firstname"
        case lastname = "lastname"
        case address = "address"
        case zipCode = "zipCode"
        case city = "city"
    }

    var member: [String:Any] {
        return [
            Value.id.rawValue:Int(),
            Value.firstname.rawValue:firstname,
            Value.lastname.rawValue:lastname,
            Value.address.rawValue:address ?? String(),
            Value.zipCode.rawValue:zipCode ?? Int(),
            Value.city.rawValue:city ?? String()
        ]
    }
}

func memberToDic(member: Member) -> [String:Any] {
    return [
        Member.Value.firstname.rawValue:member.firstname,
        Member.Value.lastname.rawValue:member.lastname,
        Member.Value.address.rawValue:member.address ?? String(),
        Member.Value.zipCode.rawValue:member.zipCode ?? Int(),
        Member.Value.city.rawValue:member.city ?? String()
    ]
}

func dicToMember(dic: [String:Any]) -> Member {
    return Member(
        id: dic[Member.Value.id.rawValue] as! Int,
        firstname: dic[Member.Value.firstname.rawValue] as! String,
        lastname: dic[Member.Value.lastname.rawValue] as! String,
        address: dic[Member.Value.address.rawValue] as? String,
        zipCode: dic[Member.Value.zipCode.rawValue] as? Int,
        city: dic[Member.Value.city.rawValue] as? String
    )
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "saved as dictionary?" Do you mean it's saved as JSON, or some other format?

Comment: @RobNapier just the dictionary in a `plist` file

Comment: `struct Address: Codable {
    let streetAddress, zipCode, city: String
}

struct Member: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let firstName, lastName: String
    let address: Address?
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly, this is the correct implementation:

```
struct Member: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var firstName: String // "first name" is two words, so capitalize "name"
    var lastName: String
    var address: String   // "No address" should be empty, not nil
    var zipCode: String   // ZIP codes are not integers
    var city: String      // "No city" should be empty, not nil
}
```

In order to save this as a plist, use PropertyListEncoder:

```
let data = try PropertyListEncoder().encode(member)
```

To read it, use PropertyListDecoder.

Codable automatically creates key mappings for your properties, so there's no need for Value.

You should strongly avoid creating or consuming `[String: Any]` dictionaries. These exist mostly due to Objective-C interfaces that could not generate strong types.

If `address`, `zipCode`, and `city` all should be set together, or not set together, then you should collect them into a single struct:

```
struct Address: Codable {
    var streetAddress: String
    var zipCode: String
    var city: String
}

struct Member: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var firstName: String // "first name" is two words, so capitalize "name"
    var lastName: String
    var address: Address?
}
```

In this case, and Optional makes sense because "empty" is not the same thing as "missing."